# what event sets the dimensions of a swfloader?

Tags: apache-flex, scaling, swfloader

I am trying to scale a swf that has been loaded via a swfloader.  When I get the complete event or the init event the dimensions of the swfloader are still zero. I don't see a value in the dimensions until I do a resize of the browser window.  The swf is just an animation.  Trying to resize the actual swf content gives inconsistent results.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of problem, it sometimes helps to simply poll the dimensions on `enterFrame` until you get some value. You could for example do this:

```
bool dimensionsSet = false
addEventListener("enterFrame", checkDimensions);

function checkDimensions(event:*):void {
    if (!dimensionsSet && width && height) {
        dimensionsSet = true;
        // Do initialization code
    }
}
```